# HHow to merge different arrays with similar object property?

Tags: arrays, object, merge, properties

I have two different arrays as below.

```
1st Array : arr1
0: {ID: '1', Name: 'Suyog Patil', IsSelected: false, Location: 'Mumbai'}
1: {ID: '2', Name: 'John Doe', IsSelected: false, Location: 'London'}
2: {ID: '3', Name: 'Santosh Sarnobat', IsSelected: false, Location: 'Panvel'}
3: {ID: '4', Name: 'Sai Panhalkar', IsSelected: false, Location: 'Belapur'}

2nd Array : arr2
0: {ID: '1', IsSelected: true}
1: {ID: '3', IsSelected: true}
```

Now, I want the replace the properties of array1 with properties of array2 where ID property is same.
So, the final array would look like (I need to get below output)

```
0: {ID: '1', Name: 'Suyog Patil', IsSelected: true, Location: 'Mumbai'}      //Replaced value
1: {ID: '2', Name: 'John Doe', IsSelected: false, Location: 'London'}
2: {ID: '3', Name: 'Santosh Sarnobat', IsSelected: true, Location: 'Panvel'} //Replaced value
3: {ID: '4', Name: 'Sai Panhalkar', IsSelected: false, Location: 'Belapur'}
```

Here, you can see, IsSelected property is replaced to true where ID equals 1 & 3.

This is what I have tried so far, but not able to achieve.

```
arr3 = [].concat(arr1, arr2);
```

But, it gives 6 results, it literally concats as the function says

Comment: Nothing jQuery specific here - you can do this without jQuery at all

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that point, anyways , thanks for modifying ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying above, I tried to solve with looping array, and it got solved.

```js
arr1 = [];
arr1.push({"ID":"1","Name":"Suyog Patil","IsSelected":false,"Location":"Mumbai"});
arr1.push({"ID":"2","Name":"John Doe","IsSelected":false,"Location":"London"});
arr1.push({"ID":"3","Name":"Santosh Sarnobat","IsSelected":false,"Location":"Panvel"});
arr1.push({"ID":"4","Name":"Sai Panhalkar","IsSelected":false,"Location":"Belapur"});

arr2 = [];
arr2.push({"ID":"1","IsSelected":true});
arr2.push({"ID":"3","IsSelected":true});

console.log("-----ARRAY 1-----");
console.log(arr1);

console.log("-----ARRAY 2-----");
console.log(arr2);

arr3 = arr1;

$(arr3).each(function(i,v){
    $(arr2).each(function(ix,vx){
        if(v.ID == vx.ID)
        {
            v.IsSelected = vx.IsSelected;
        }
    })
});


console.log("-----ARRAY 3-----");
console.log(arr3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-jQuery version using much simplified code

```js
const arr1 = [
  {"ID":"1","Name":"Suyog Patil","IsSelected":false,"Location":"Mumbai"},
  {"ID":"2","Name":"John Doe","IsSelected":false,"Location":"London"},
  {"ID":"3","Name":"Santosh Sarnobat","IsSelected":false,"Location":"Panvel"},
  {"ID":"4","Name":"Sai Panhalkar","IsSelected":false,"Location":"Belapur"}
],
arr2 = [{"ID":"1","IsSelected":true}, {"ID":"3","IsSelected":true}],
arr3 = arr1.map(item => ({...item,IsSelected: arr2.find(({ID}) => ID === item.ID) || false}))


console.log("-----ARRAY 3-----");
console.log(arr3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```